# creating a silent wav file with ffmpeg

Tags: java, ffmpeg, wav

i want to know how to create ffmpeg file that is silent for a certain length that is dependant on a variable called DIFF, this is what i got so far that doesn't seem to work

```
// creates a wav file for the lenth of the silence
File silence = new File(root + "silence.wav");
String lthacommand = "ffmpeg -filter_complex aevalsrc=0 -t " + diff
+ " " + silence.getAbsolutePath();
new ThreadControl().executeCommand(lthacommand);
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Is there an error message?

Comment: doesnt change the wav length

Comment: specify the duration as a option. `aevalsrc=0:d=10`

Comment: Not the solution to your issue, and it doesn't really matter very much, but [`anullsrc`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#anullsrc) is the proper tool for the job of generating silence instead of `aevalsrc`, and is probably 2x faster.